# � appears using character_limiter() with strip_tags() and utf-8 charset

Tags: php, codeigniter, character-encoding

I'm getting � characters when I combine Codeigniter's `character_limiter()` with PHP's native `strip_tags()`. Here is the code I'm using:

```
<?php echo character_limiter(strip_tags($block->body), 60); ?>
```

`$block->body` is an HTML string stored in the database. I do not get this unexpected output if I use only one of the functions. It looks like this:

[image]

This is what the HTML looks like:

[image]

<sup>I didn't paste the actual HTML because the string would be modified by posting it here, see below</sup>

Here is the Codeigniter function `character_limiter`:

```
function character_limiter($str, $n = 500, $end_char = '&#8230;')
{
    if (strlen($str) < $n)
    {
        return $str;
    }

    $str = preg_replace("/\s+/", ' ', str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), ' ', $str));

    if (strlen($str) <= $n)
    {
        return $str;
    }

    $out = "";
    foreach (explode(' ', trim($str)) as $val)
    {
        $out .= $val.' ';

        if (strlen($out) >= $n)
        {
            $out = trim($out);
            return (strlen($out) == strlen($str)) ? $out : $out.$end_char;
        }
    }
}
```

I figured out that there was some invisible character or something that may have been causing this, because when I pasted the HTML into a text editor, then back into the "HTML source editor" in the image (which is just TinyMCE), then saved it, the weird characters disappeared.

I am using the utf-8 character set across the board (everywhere possible). The original data did come from a dump of an unknown database, and was imported with an SQL client. However, when I saved the existing string (in the CMS), nothing changed.

I can't connect the dots between these two functions causing this output when used together, and I **do not** get the � characters normally. I *only* see this output when I use:

```
character_limiter(strip_tags($html))
```

What could be causing this, and how can I prevent it?

**Note:** I definitely want to use the `character_limiter` function, or a variation of it. It makes an ellipsis at the end of the string if its length is longer than the second param. Using it alone (without `strip_tags`) works perfectly fine (no weird characters).

**Update:** For anyone that can't reproduce this, I put an SQL file online that demos the issue. I am importing this with [MySQL Query Browser](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/query-browser/en/). I only get this output it *seems* when the HTML comes from the database. Here is the link (ignore the content, it's the client's fault): http://wesleymurch.com/test/test1.sql

Comment: I just tried your code and I can't reproduce the issue; tried utf-8 and ansi, the same. The only difference is my html string is hardcoded, no database then. Don't really know if it really is the mixing of the 2 functions, I don't see why they could output that carachter...

Comment: Yeah I knew this would be hard to test but I assure you that it is in fact happening, let me see if I can get a file online with the actual string... EDIT: Not sure how to do it without the invisible characters getting "removed", any ideas? Also, this is the first time I've seen this ever, only happened after importing data from an old site.

Comment: I have no clue, I searched for bugs in the strip_tags() function but found none relevant...Especially if you say that is just the combination of the two in this order (if you change it? strip_tags(character_limiter...)) that gives the problem.

Comment: I put an SQL file online that hopefully can help to reproduce the issue, I tested it and it worked for me. @DamienPirsy: If I reverse the order, the output is OK.

Comment: Saw you quite solved id. Anyway, with a fresh DB, phpmyadmin under Xampp Windows the problem doesn't appear.

Comment: @DamienPirsy: Thank you very much for checking it out. It's very hard to debug. shox's fix solved the problem, but I'm still looking for an explanation.

Comment: Pardon my limited knowledge, I knew just now of the existence of  [preg_last_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-last-error.php) and I wonder if the flag PREG_BAD_UTF8_ERROR or others might actually show what's happening in that line. Give it a try, maybe it's helpful

Comment: There didn't seem to be any PCRE errors. I may try asking again with  a different context and a better test case, it's something to do with the line shox removed though - didn't even need the multibyte string functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

� replacement character used to replace an unknown or unprintable character
in php usually we solve this issue using multibyte string functions .
use mb_substr with strip tags like :

```
mb_substr( strip_tags($text) , 0,300 ,'UTF-8' );//or what ever your charset
```

or you maybe modify the codeigniter function and use Multibyte String Functions .

**UPDATE**

```
function character_limiter($str, $n = 500, $end_char = '&#8230;')
{
    if (mb_strlen($str) < $n)
    {
        return $str;
    }

    $str = mb_ereg_replace("\s+", ' ', str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), ' ', $str));

    if (mb_strlen($str) <= $n)
    {
        return $str;
    }

    $out = "";
    foreach (explode(' ', trim($str)) as $val)
    {
        $out .= $val.' ';

        if (mb_strlen($out) >= $n)
        {
            $out = trim($out);
            return (mb_strlen($out) == mb_strlen($str)) ? $out : $out.$end_char;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that did not work. This is a copy paste of my code: `character_limiter(mb_substr(strip_tags($block->body), 0, 300, 'UTF-8' ), 60);` Besides, I want to use the `character_limiter()` function to take advantage of the ellipsis if the string is longer than the param.

Comment: No just use it without character limiter e.g.
`mb_substr(strip_tags($block->body), 0, 60, 'UTF-8' );`

Comment: Yeah, exact same result. It's very weird. I wish I could demo it on codepad but it won't show up. Do you understand why I want to use `character_limiter()`? That is the whole point of the post, I **don't** get that output unless I combine the two functions, and either one by itself is fine.

Comment: I tried replacing the function with your code, added a `Hello` to the beginning of the return value to make sure the new code was executing, but had no luck (same exact output). Any clue as to *why* this is happening? That's what I *really* want to know. If you look at the screen shots, the character appears as if it was "inserted".

Comment: I think it should work now !
see this for more info http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)

Comment: Still no changes, it's very weird. This comes from the database (utf8 charset), and that data came from an SQL dump file. I re-imported the data and still have the issue.

Comment: try to comment(remove)     `$str = preg_replace("/\s+/", ' ', str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), ' ', $str));`

Comment: Commenting out that line, with your code, fixed it! What's going on here, can you explain? What is that line doing and why did commenting it out solve the problem? What is causing that character to show up? I know what the � *is*, but why did it appear? What are the effects of removing that line, and why only with `strip_tags()` did it appear?

Comment: Oh, so it was that one?? but why? and why only when used together with strip_tags()? :-o

Comment: shox: Thank you very much for this workaround, rest assured I will return to upvote, and I will certainly accept the answer if I cannot get a better explanation. I'm still quite interested in the cause of this.

Comment: Going to accept this answer, but possibly reopen the issue when I can make a better test case (I've got more important things to do right now). Thanks a lot for the quick-fix.